# How to split XML file using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

Please refer to [sample XML file](http://oval.mitre.org/rep-data/5.10/org.mitre.oval/v/platform/microsoft.windows.server.2008.r2.xml) I am using in my project. I need to break (split) this file according to "objects" in XML file. Fortunately, there is a [tool](http://ovalutils.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ovalutils/trunk/OVAL_Splitter/src/org/mitre/ovalutils/) available which splits the file using XSLT. Please refer to XSL [here](http://pastebin.com/bzXJRqK0)

When objects are in the form like below-

```
<registry_object id="oval:org.mitre.oval:obj:16243" version="1" xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#windows">
  <hive>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE</hive>
  <key>SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\IPFS</key>
  <name>DisplayName</name>
</registry_object>
```

the tool split doesn't file properly- the hive/key etc information is missing. [Sample output](http://pastebin.com/yyLKK4qu) Refer to [this](http://pastebin.com/aTCXdamB)

When the objects are in the form like below-

```
<registry_object id="oval:org.mitre.oval:obj:16179" version="2" comment="Uninstall\IPFS\DisplayName" xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#windows">
  <set xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
    <object_reference>oval:org.mitre.oval:obj:16050</object_reference>
    <object_reference>oval:org.mitre.oval:obj:16243</object_reference>
  </set>
</registry_object>
```

it works just fine. Refer to [this](http://pastebin.com/cEPuyqKf). The code which is being used to split the file according to objects is-

```
<xsl:when test="contains($inputId, ':obj:')">
<xsl:for-each select="$definitionDoc//oval-def:objects/child::*[@id = $inputId]/descendant::*/*:object_reference/text() | $definitionDoc//oval-def:objects/child::*[@id = $inputId]/descendant::*/*:filter/text() | 
                $definitionDoc//oval-def:objects/child::*[@id = $inputId]/descendant::*/*:var_ref/text() | 
                $definitionDoc//oval-def:objects/child::*[@id = $inputId]/descendant::*/@var_ref">              

                <xsl:variable name="returnedIds" select="ovalfn:getAllIds(($processedIds | $inputId), .)"/>
                xsl:sequence select="$returnedIds | $processedIds | $inputId | ."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Since I don't know about XSLT I don't know how to fix this issue. Can someone please provide some guidance on how this can be resolved? I think I need to update above XSL code so that it can extract "objects" when they don't have "object_reference"

Comment: So, what output is produced in each of the two cases and what output must be produced instead? Also, you havent provided the complete XML document (as minimal as possible, please) and the complete XML transformation, so there is no way to reproduce the claims that with one of the XML document (not provided) the transformation (not provided) produces unwanted output (not provided), which is unwanted due to some reason (not specified/explained), but with the second XML document, the result (not provided) is "good" due to some reason (not specified/explained). Please. provide all the missing data

Comment: I had provided the sample document and XSL used by means of linking. You can click on "sample XML file" and "here" in first para of my question to see reference XML document and XSL. I have now updated the question with good and bad output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by updating the xsl query as-

```
$definitionDoc//oval-def:objects/child::*[@id = $inputId]/descendant::*/.
```